# Error 91-With no establecido

Tags: excel, vba

¿A que se debe este error en el código?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Dim FSO, folder, subFlds, fld, ParentFolder, path

Dim oFSO As Object
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ParentFolder = oFSO.GetFile(ActiveWorkbook.FullName).ParentFolder.ParentFolder.path

path = ParentFolder + "\Base de Datos\"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(path)
Set subFlds = folder.SubFolders

For Each fld In subFlds
    List1.AddItem fld.Name
Next
```

Comment: ¿En qué línea te da el error? Yo lo he replicado, omitiendo la parte que dice `List1.AddItem fld.Name` y funciona perfecto. ¿Puede ser que el Listbox no se llame así? ¿Qué tipo de control es? ¿Tienes esto en un formulario o en un módulo normal?

Comment: No has dimensionado la variable List1, revisa que tipo de variable te conviene.

Answer (score 0):

Ese error normalmente aparece cuando estás trabajando con objetos y quieres hacer que un objeto forme parte de otro o sea exactamente igual.

puede deberse porque no estás utilizando la palabra SET en una linea de codigo como la siguiente:

```
SET objetox = objetoy
```